# How To Set Width/Height Of An Android Relative Layout Via Programming?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am working on a Android apps using Android Studio and just a new to it. I want to make outer main layout on `currentscreenwidth + 300dp` and height should be 100% means `match_parent`. In that main outer layout, I am creating two layouts. Inner first layout will have a fix 300dp width and the other layout should have `screenwidth+300dp`. For that I have to main layout width `currentscreenwidth + 300dp` becasue one of my inner layout have fixed `300dp` and other one have `match_parent` and placed in a row. For this I am using below codes but its not working. When I manually write width about 1000dp to outer layout then my inner layout work fine as I want but I want the fix calculation of `currentscreenwidth + 300dp`. How Can I Do This?

### activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainbody"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"   //currentscreenwidth + 300dp
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.domain.project.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menubar"
        android:layout_width="300dp"   //300dp
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menubar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"    //currentscreenwidth
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java:

```
package com.domain.project;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get Width And Height Of Screen On Page Load
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
        float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
        float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;

        int width = Math.round(dpWidth);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainbody);
        //rl.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
        rl.getLayoutParams().width = width + 300;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easies thing would be to create a custom `ViewGroup`.

Measure and layout the children yourself. The 300dp one would be called with `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`, the screenwidth one you could just pass through your viewgroups `MeasureSpec.AT_MOST` or `UNSPECIFIED` and it should measure to the full screen width.

This sample uses 300px to not further complicate it.

```
public class SomeLayout extends ViewGroup {

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        getChildAt(0).measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(300, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), heightMeasureSpec);
        getChildAt(1).measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth() + getChildAt(1).getMeasuredWidth(),
                Math.max(getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight(), getChildAt(1).getMeasuredHeight()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        getChildAt(0).layout(l, t, l + getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth(), b);
        getChildAt(1).layout(l + getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth(), t,
                l + getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth() + getChildAt(1).getMeasuredWidth(), b);
    }
}
```

Use it like

```
<SomeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"></RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"></RelativeLayout>
</SomeLayout>
```